# Workaround for_each meta argument

Tags: foreach, terraform, terragrunt

Suppose I have a Terragrunt configuration sitting on top of all the platform-boundary Databricks projects, that has a cluster module running. This module loops over the locals block which is defined in every PB `main.tf` as such:

```
locals {
    #... other local vars
    clusters = {
      clusterA = {
        name = "clusterA"
        #... other cluster config
      },
      clusterB = {
        name = "clusterB"
        #... other cluster config
      }, ...
    }
}

## main.tf
```

All the cluster names are unique. I wish now to delete every single cluster except for clusterX from a specific platform-boundary.
My goal is to basically set the `for_each` within the cluster module to an empty set whenever I don't it doesn't loop over this specific cluster, but if it bumps into it I want the module to be executed.

I'm struggling to come up with the right conditional for this, the closest I got to a solution was the following:

```
locals{
    run_cluster_module = contains(keys(local.clusters), "clusterX")
}

module "cluster" {
    for_each = local.run_cluster_module ? local.clusters : {}
    #... other module attributes 

## terragrunt.hcl
```

This somehow raises inconsistency type errors. Any tips?

Comment: Wrong with the current code. Any specific errors?

Comment: I've also tried this map: 
`for_each = { for cluster_name, cluster in local.clusters : cluster_name => local.clusters[cluster_name].name == "clusterX" ? {} : cluster }` and the type of error that is come up is something like "The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The 'true'
value includes object attribute "some-cluster", which is
absent in the 'false' value."

Comment: Please update the question with the error message instead of adding a comment. Please also ensure the code is consistent with the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{ ... }` syntax in Terraform produces a value of an object type. In some cases Terraform is able to infer automatically that you intended to use a map value instead and convert it, but in this situation Terraform isn't sure enough about what you're intending to do, so it's not performing any automatic conversions.

The error message then describes the mismatch between the two different object types, in the hope that it will help you add the appropriate type conversions or other information to clarify what data type you intend the conditional expression to produce.

In this case I would suggest explicitly converting both values to maps. For example:

```
locals {
    #... other local vars
  clusters = tomap({
    clusterA = {
      name = "clusterA"
      #... other cluster config
    },
    clusterB = {
      name = "clusterB"
      #... other cluster config
    }, ...
  })
}

module "cluster" {
  for_each = local.run_cluster_module ? local.clusters : tomap({})

  # ...
}
```

This tells Terraform that you intend `local.clusters` to be a map of objects rather than an object itself. I can't predict exactly what that type would be with only the partial value of `local.clusters`, but with only the `name` attribute as you showed in your snippet `local.clusters` would have the following type:

```
map(object({
  name = string
}))
```

`tomap({})` is special in that it produces "a map of unknown type" -- there's not enough information here to infer what the element type ought to be -- but the conditional expression should notice that one result has a known element type and the other does not, and thus it can automatically specialize the map of unknown element type into a map of known element type matching the type of `local.clusters`.

---

Making this change might cause Terraform to begin complaining about a different part of your configuration instead. Giving Terraform more information will allow it to be more specific about where the problem is, and so it's likely that the new error will have the same root cause as the original error, but with additional information Terraform can make more confident assumptions about what you were intending to do and thus describe the problem more specifically.

In particular, note that all objects in a map of objects must have *the same object type*, which means that they must have the same attribute names and types. If there are some attributes that only apply to a subset of your clusters, you can set them to `null` to make the types agree while still representing that some of the attributes are not populated.